# Serilog not logging to MariaDb database

Tags: c#, .net-core, mariadb, serilog, .net-5

I'm using Serilog in a .Net Core 5 console application to log to a MariaDb database on Armbian Buster (i.e. Debian 10) on an Orange Pi Zero (essentially a Raspberry Pi).

This is how I'm initializing Serilog:

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Sinks.MariaDB;
using Serilog.Sinks.MariaDB.Extensions;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File("logs/log.txt", 
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Month, 
                    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}", 
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
                .WriteTo.MariaDB(
                    connectionString: @"server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=abcde;database=mydb",
                    tableName: "Logs",
                    autoCreateTable: true,
                    useBulkInsert: false,
                    options: new MariaDBSinkOptions()
                    )
                .CreateLogger();
    }
```

It is writing to the console and to the text file, but not to the MariaDb database. It should create the table and log to it. Just in case, I manually created the table, but it's still not logging. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Is the console app also on the Pi? Your connection string says localhost.

Comment: You can also gain more insight with [SelfLog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics)

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, the app is running on the Orange Pi. And the MariaDb database is also on the Pi.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks, I think Selflog will help me. I will try it out tonight and let you know.